# $p$-Sylow subgroups are enough for surjectivity of homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm reading a book  and I'm a little rusty in finite group theory and in particular Sylow theory, so I gently ask you for references for such result. This is probably standard. The situation is as follows

Let $G$ and $H$ be finite groups.

Say $f\colon G\to H$ is a homomorphism, and we want to check surjectivity.

The autor claims it is enough to check surjectivity for $p$-Sylow subgroups of $H$.

Now, I'm not sure if this is because of some aditional hypotheses that exist in the groups in question for my particular case, or if it is some general thing that always happens. I will be happy to find out.

I suppose that, if every element $h$ of $H$ could be written as a product $h=p_{1}...p{k}$ with $p_{k}$'s in various $p$-Sylow subgroups of $H$, then we are done, because then
\begin{equation}
h=f(g_{1})\dots f(g_{k})=f(g_{1}\dots g_{k}).
\end{equation}
Now, how to do this? I guess that we could look at the order of $h$ and find out something, but I came up with nothing. Thanks for any help or reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument is to consider the order of the image of $f$.

Say that $|H| = p_1^{n_1} \dots p_k^{n_k}$ and the image of $f$ is order $p_1^{m_1} \dots p_k^{m_k}$.  Here $f$ is surjective if and only if $m_i = n_i$ for all $i$.

Now we observe that if the image of $f$ contains a $p_i$-Sylow subgroup $P_i$ of $H$, then $m_i = n_i$.  This follows since $p_i^{n_i} = |P_i|$ divides the order of any subgroup containing $P_i$.

e: Note that if you fix specific Sylow subgroups $P_1, \ldots P_k$, then it is not always the case that every element of $G$ can be written in the form $p_1\ldots p_k$.  The smallest counterexample I can come up with for this is $A_5$, for which note that since $(1 5) (3 2)(1 4 3 )(1 2 3 4 5) $ is the identity, the list of 60 products $p_1p_2p_3$ contains repeats and thus is not the entirety of $A_5$.

This can be fixed by noting that $H$ is always the subgroup *generated by* $P_1, P_2, \dots P_k$, in other words every element $h$ can be written in the form $q_1q_2\dots q_l$, where each $q_j$ lies in some $P_i$. Then $h = f(g_1)\dots f(g_l) = f(g_1\dots g_l)$ as desired.

However, to see that the subgroup generated by $P_1, P_2, \dots P_k$ is all of $H$, it is easiest to consider order, similar to the argument above.

Comment: I just have to thank you for taking the time and adressing why my approach might not work. Thanks a lot.